# string printing in an API server call but not outside of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, api

I can't figure out why for the "2nd badge print" nothing is even printed in the console, but for the "1st badge print" I do see what I get?!

```
-(void)runBadgeCall{
    NSLog(@"---RAN BADGE CALL---");
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"getCountForBadge",@"command",nil]
                               onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
                                   if([json objectForKey:@"badgeCount"]!= NULL){
                                   _badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"badgeCount"]];
                                     NSLog(@"1st badge print %@",_badgeValue);
                                   }
                               }];
    NSLog(@"2nd badge print %@",_badgeValue);


  }
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with threads but I don't understand why. If i someone can explain it, that'll be great!

Answer (score 1):

Check the top of the console. It looks like your logging the completion handler of an asynchronous operation, in which case, the order in which your log statements get called will look like this:

```
NSLog(@"---RAN BADGE CALL---");
NSLog(@"2nd badge print %@",_badgeValue);
NSLog(@"1st badge print %@",_badgeValue);
```

"2nd badge print" might just be hiding above the JSON response.